# Why following Bootstrap columns fail when using img inside a column?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid, rendering

Following markup fails to render correctly when using img tag inside a grid column:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeholdit.co//i/48x72?text=USER\nERROR" /></div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">Description</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeholdit.co//i/48x72?text=USER\nERROR" /></div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">Description</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeholdit.co//i/48x72?text=USER\nERROR" /></div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">Description</div>
  <div class="col-sm-4"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeholdit.co//i/48x72?text=USER\nERROR" /></div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">Description</div>
</div>
```

It will work perfectly if I remove the image and replace it with text.

Comment: A row should contain 12 columns. Yours contains 48.

Comment: This isn't really to do with the images specifically. Your markup would result in a similar broken grid if you replaced the image with a long block of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not nesting your columns properly. There can only be 12 columns per row and you're trying to fit 4 rows worth into one.

You should look at [the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid) a little closer.

> If more than 12 columns are placed within a single row, each group of
>   extra columns will, as one unit, wrap onto a new line.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeholdit.co//i/48x72?text=USER\nERROR" /></div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">Description</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeholdit.co//i/48x72?text=USER\nERROR" /></div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">Description</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeholdit.co//i/48x72?text=USER\nERROR" /></div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">Description</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://placeholdit.co//i/48x72?text=USER\nERROR" /></div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">Description</div>
</div>
```

Comment: For realz? I always understood that it would make "virtual rows" when column count 12 is exceeded and that there is no need for a new row element?

Comment: @user1271930 yes, for realz

Comment: But how does this comply into this situation "each group of extra columns will, as one unit, wrap onto a new line"? Afaik, it states that it should do just like I stated and create "virtual rows" i.e. "wrap onto a new line" as per documentation?

Comment: When you do that, they wrap, but flow is broken. In that case, they stack as they can, creating inconsistencies. Don't be lazy, just wrap them properly. ;)

Comment: Can you give an insight from technical perspective? Seems that this is some heavy lifting on the CMD backend to calculate items and render new row elements per column count (which also has to be predefined). But at least I know I've been "abusing" Bootstrap like this before and never had similar problem for example on ads listing page where I had just single row element that included items in 3 columns and multiple rows...

Comment: Every `.row` class has `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements that clear the flow. This is what established a new row as a clean slate. When you jam a bunch of columns into one row they will not get reset and will not properly stack.

Comment: Okay, so maybe documentation could just state that "it won't work". At least I get a totally wrong impression from the docs and I still wonder that why has it been working just fine in my earlier projects...

Comment: My guess would be that if you use only text content, or content of same high, or really long column divs, then things will stack just fine. Doesn't make it right.

Comment: Okay, I was just reviewing my old test of multiple columns in a single row and while every column has exactly the same definition e.g. col-md-4 col-xs-1 it works fine. So for me it seems that one can skip row control logic on backend and just wrap columns inside column which on the contrary is allowed per docs.